# Composite primary key plus a separate (surrogate) id column for foreign key references

Tags: database-design, primary-key, erd, surrogate-key, candidate-key

I am trying to build a database about *locations* like so:

- Country → Region → Town

Countries will be populated with a list of pre-defined worldwide countries, regions & towns are input by users.

Region may not apply to every location and so a blank string will be allowed (hence the many to many link table).

This is the best design I have come up with:

[image: ER Diagram]

The `town_id` column is set to AUTO_INCREMENT & UNIQUE. It is then used as a foreign key reference in other tables.

The `town` column on its own is not UNIQUE as you may have the same town name in multiple places.

Is the `towns` table correct?

The reason I ask is because it just seems odd to me to have the `town_id` as the reference, however this cannot be included or used as the primary key (because if it did, it would cause duplicates)?

I would welcome feedback if this approach is correct.

Comment: town_id sounds like it should be the reference. Numeric (fast compare), auto_increment (ensures unique), and unique are all good properties one would want of a primary key. Perhaps I'm confused as to what's causing your confusion, given these properties.

Comment: @JaazCole - sorry for any confusion, but are you suggesting town_id should be the primary key, or what I have proposed is best?

Comment: Based on what you described about the properties of town_id, I would recommend using it as the only primary key (provided my first comment is true), and the Region/Country IDs should only be foreign keys. This would allow you to have duplicate town names. You might want to put a unique index on country_id, region_id, town, as I'm pretty sure there's no political subdivision that has two towns of the same name, and it would reflect that business logic.

Comment: @JaazCole - haha ok great, this is where my knowledge let me down! i did not realise that you could add a unique index to apply to multiple columns as you have suggested (to country_id, region_id & town). This is exactly what I was trying to do. thanks for your help. do you want to post this as answer, or should i?

Comment: I added it, it's been fun.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the help @JaazCole - that was the last piece in the puzzle for my db...!(at least I hope so! ha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using it (town_id) as the only primary key (provided my first comment is true about the increment and uniqueness), and the Region/Country IDs should only be foreign keys. This would allow you to have duplicate town names.

You might want to put a unique index on country_id, region_id, town, as I'm pretty sure there's no political subdivision that has two towns of the same name, and it would reflect that business logic.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can create a primary key for region and reference region in country and reference country in town so the data will be normalized for 3nf. like this
[image]